# Error while sending a timestamp data to PostgreSQL DB. (using python)

Tags: python, postgresql, timestamp

I have a variable that contains timestamp data. I want to send
it to PostgreSQL DB using python. While executing the code I am
getting the following error:

> server connected database connected
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "check_module.py", line 18,
> in 
> cd.curs.execute(b) psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "10" LINE 1: ...witch, temperature_setpoint) VALUES(24,2021-04-27
> 10:52:02.9...
> ^
>
> ------------------ (program exited with code: 1)
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

Following is the code in python.

```
timestamp1= (datetime.fromisoformat('2021-04-27 10:52:02.901103'))
timestamp2= (datetime.fromisoformat('2021-04-27 10:52:04.701057')) 
    
b = "INSERT INTO zone_measurement(zone_d, ch_timestamp, timestamp, zone_temp, zone_speed, zone_cycle, s_control, lswitch, temp_set) VALUES(24,{},{}, 21.64, 0.0, NULL, false, 0.0, 19.0);".format(timestamp1,timestamp2)
    
curs.execute(b)
conn.commit()
curs.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this,

```
timestamp1= (datetime.fromisoformat('2021-04-27 10:52:02.901103'))
timestamp2= (datetime.fromisoformat('2021-04-27 10:52:04.701057'))

b = "INSERT INTO zone_measurement(zone_d, ch_timestamp, timestamp, zone_temp, zone_speed, zone_cycle, s_control, lswitch, temp_set) 
                           VALUES(%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s, %s,%s);"
val = (24,timestamp1,timestamp2, 21.64, 0.0, NULL, false, 0.0, 19.0)

curs.execute(b, val)
conn.commit()
curs.close()
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Can you tell me the working principle? and also about the problem in my program?

Comment: @Nithin, Please vote for the solution that worked for you.

Comment: The problem in your program is evident by comparing to what you should be doing, [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries), and what the answer does.

Comment: @Raky Hi I am not able to vote.  "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded." This is what they say.....

Comment: Dear @Nithin, I just mentioned it. I didn't ask for it. Its a basic courtesy that I used to miss after the getting the help. So just a polite reminder and an attempt to imbibe Forum courtesies. Sorry, I offended you or made you feel something else.

Comment: @Raky Hi, you did not offend me. I really wanted to thank you in every way. I am very new to this community and don't even know many options on the website....   I am really thankful to you. and this is awesome that someone is here to help you. Thanks again :)